# How to get `for i in $(...)` delimited by lines in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, newline, whitespace

```
#!/bin/bash

get_data() {
  echo foo
  echo "bar baz"
}

for i in $(get_data); do
   echo "got: $i"
done
```

actual output is

```
got: foo
got: bar
got: baz
```

what I want is

```
got: foo
got: bar baz
```

How do I get the variable `i` in `for i in $(...)` to be filled per-line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Comment: `for i in $(..)` is a broken construct; it is subject to **word-splitting** (which you can somehow manage by setting `IFS`) and worse, to **glob expansion**

Comment: See also [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
get_data | while IFS= read -r i ; do
  echo "got $i"
done
```

The reason why you are not getting what you want with `for` is that `$(get_data)` gets expanded by bash to `foo bar baz`; by default, new lines are treated as word boundaries like space and nothing more. Similarly, using `for` to loop over contents of a file (`for line in $(cat file)`) will not work as expected.

P.S. You could modify the IFS (field separator) like this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

as suggested in one of the comments; however I prefer my solution as more explicit and less error-prone.

Comment: Don't use a `while`-loop in a pipeline as it is executed in a sub-shell. Changes to, or definition of variables will not be transferred to the parent. Just use `while IFS= read -r line; do cmd "$line"; done < <(get_data)`.  (See [BashFAQ#024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024))

Comment: The `read` command should have been `IFS= read -r i`. `IFS=` is in order to preserve leading and trailing blanks. `-r` option is in order to prevent backslashes from being an escape character.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin forgot about the leading and trailing space. Updated my comment. Thanks.

Comment: @kvantour: I actually prefer the subshell solution. I find this `while ... done < < ...` idiom hard to read and confusing. Is there any other reason to favor it apart of having local variables?